# Multi select function not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, html

I am using a javascript `multi select` function for `listbox` along with `php` code. In the interface we can select multiple elements but when I use the php code to get the values from it, it retrieves only one value. Can some one please tell me what is wrong?

javascript:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $("select").multiselect();
});
</script>
```

HTML code:

```
<select title="Basic example" multiple="multiple" name="example-basic" size="5">
    <option value="Sgoop">Sgoop</option>
    <option value="Monet">Monet</option>
    <option value="Hive">Hive</option>
    <option value="Mahout">Mahout</option>
    <option value="R">R</option>
    <option value="Storm">Storm</option>
    <option value="Flume">Flume</option>
    <option value="Solr">Solr</option>
    <option value="Python">Python</option>
    <option value="Splunk">Splunk</option>
    <option value="Ruby">Ruby</option>
    <option value="perl">perl</option>
    </select>
```

mysql code:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO details (name, type, domain, rights, description, author, version, download)
VALUES
('$_POST[compname]','$_POST[examplebasic]','$_POST[examplebasic2]','$_POST[examplebasic3]','$_POST[textarea]','$_POST[name]',1,0)";
```

after changing the examplebasic to examplebasic[] now i am getting an array to string conversion error. what can i do to resolve this

Comment: The answer to your problem is already given by @Alireza41, I am just hinting you, do not use this code in production site. It is bad practice to insert post data to database directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT

---

change name to

```
name="example-basic[]"
```

and in your php code :

```
$options = json_encode( $_POST['example-basic'] );

// and for populating you can use `json_decode` to get the array again
```

---

or you can split array items with `,` then insert it to database field :

```
$options = implode( ',', $_POST['example-basic'] );
```

see [implode php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) for more description

```
// then for populating use `explode` to convert it to array

$sql="INSERT INTO details (name, type, domain, rights, description, author, version, download)

VALUES ('$_POST[compname]','$options','example','example2','$_POST[textarea]','$_POST[name]',1,0)";
```

Comment: I am using it to get values and store it in the database also. Now its giving me an array to string conversion error. Check the code i have edited the mysql code also

Comment: just get the array and insert each option to the database

Comment: i have to manually code in the options? what if i dont know how many will be selected

Comment: it is left for the users decision how can i hard code that part.

Comment: you can use `json_encode` to convert array to string then insert it to database

Comment: see i am selecting some values like perl, r, hive. I can use php's post or get methods to get those values but how will i enter them to the database dynamically?

Comment: where do you want to insert these information? insert into description field?

Comment: please be more explicit to resolving the problem

Comment: see now i can get the values from the list box as an array. But how to insert them on to the database fields?